# How to use python and mongodb on the gitlab (CI/CD)

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a problem when I was used CI/CD on the gitlab. I always use "python:latest" but it is 2.7.5 version, but I want to use python2.7.15 or python3.7. How can I install it?

[image]

```
-

image: python:latest

services:
  - mongo:latest

variables:
  MONGO_DB: ipc_alert

cache:
  paths:
  - ~/.cache/pip/

before_script:
  - python -V 
  - pip install -r req.txt

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
   - echo 'Testing'
```

Answer (score 0):

On the image you're posting, you have a different problem. You cannot find django on a valid version for your requirements.

About the question itself, if you want to test against multiple versions, you need to create more than one test. For example:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
   - echo 'Testing'
```

That's will be:

```
test-python2.7:
  stage: test
  image: python:2.7
  script:
   - echo 'Testing'
test-python3.4:
  stage: test
  image: python:3.4
  script:
   - echo 'Testing'
test-python3.5:
  stage: test
  image: python:3.5
  script:
   - echo 'Testing'
test-python3.6:
  stage: test
  image: python:3.6
  script:
   - echo 'Testing'
test-python3.7:
  stage: test
  image: python:3.7
  script:
   - echo 'Testing'
test-python.latest:
  stage: test
  image: python:latest
  script:
   - echo 'Testing'
```

However, maybe this doesn't work, because you're using a "Shell executor". If I remember correctly, this runner execute your code against the current machine. You need to install docker and create a new runner who uses these docker. Without it, you cannot test against different environments / versions.

One exception to this, are if you have all python versions you need installed on your machine, and calls each python concrete version. It depends on your environment, but you can check on /usr/bin if you have multiple python versions. On my machine, I have on /usr/bin these ones:

```
maqui@kanade:~$ python -V
Python 2.7.15+
maqui@kanade:~$ python2.6 -V
Python 2.6.8
maqui@kanade:~$ python2.7 -V
Python 2.7.15+
maqui@kanade:~$ python3.6 -V
Python 3.6.8rc1
maqui@kanade:~$ python3.7 -V
Python 3.7.2rc1
```

(As you can see, python is an alias for python2.7).